# Latex tables in Quarto

Tags: latex, quarto

I am using Quarto to build a presentation in reveal js format.

How can I output latex tables in my presentation? I am able to output latex formulas using the `$$...$$` syntax. Yet, when I do

```
$$
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 \\ \midrule
A        & B        \\
C        & C       
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
$$
```

The table is not shown and in VS Code I receive the error message **Quarto: Help Latex Error "Unknown environment table**

Is there a way to show latex tables in Quarto reveal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`parse-latex`](https://github.com/tarleb/parse-latex) filter:

```
---
title: "Test"
format: revealjs
filters:
  - parse-latex
---
```

[image]

````
## table 

```{=latex}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
Header 1 & Header 2 \\ \midrule
A        & B        \\
C        & C       
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```
````